# CardLayout won't show the Cards

Tags: java

I'm trying to use the CardLayout to show differently sorted JLists in my Software but it doesn't quite work out since as I implemented the different Panels containing the JList, it doesn't show any of them.

```
        JPanel cardHolder = new JPanel();
        cardHolder.setLayout(new CardLayout());

        JScrollPane standPane = new JScrollPane();
        JScrollPane profPane = new JScrollPane();
        JScrollPane semPane = new JScrollPane();

        cardHolder.add(standPane, "STANDARD");
        cardHolder.add(profPane, "PROF");
        cardHolder.add(semPane, "SEMESTER");

        standPane.add(vorlesungen);
        profPane.add(vorlesungenProf);
        semPane.add(vorlesungenSem);

        CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout)cardHolder.getLayout();
        cardLayout.show(cardHolder, "STANDARD");

        v.add(cardHolder, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: My suggestion for debugging this sort of thing is to set the background of every panel to a different color. Then you will see where your panels are.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Realized now the problem aren't the cards but instead the JList not being shown.